# js date's month and day problem in my code

Tags: javascript, date

I have problem about date in js

When I use this code, myDate is to be 
    Tue Apr 07 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00).

Like 04 is month 06 is day but it is wrong for me.

I want to have "05/06/2020" (05 is day 06 is month). Where is my problem?

```js
var voucherDate = "04/06/2020"
moment(voucherDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY').format('DD/MM/YYYY');
var myDate = new Date(voucherDate);
myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 1);
console.log(myDate)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.26.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The 2nd line is useless, it formats a date which is thrown away?

Comment: The parse algorithms defined for `Date` are quite strict in what they can handle. Different browers add different algorithms. If you can use momentjs then use it. It will make this so much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make a call to `moment` but then you don't use its result, and you create a `Date` instead. Try

```
var myDate = moment(voucherDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY').add(1, 'days').format('DD/MM/YYYY');
```

Comment: the format for the input is missing and calling `format` will return a string, which he won't be able to add +1 day

Comment: @dube well spotted

Comment: it is not working sir result is same "07/04/2020" not "05/06/2020"

Comment: @joe Missed specifying the input format as dube spotted. Amended my answer.